# How to validate proper case of a string?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have table in SQL server having a column test,

```
test
-------
This Is Another Test
This is another Test
```

i want to query the table which should return me the output:

expected output:

```
test
-------
This Is Another Test
```

the query i have written doesn't give me the expected output checking for proper case:

```
select * from proptest where test like '[A-Z][a-z]{2}(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*$';
```

How to check if a value is proper case or not?

Comment: Column collation?

Comment: What's this got to do with Java here?

Comment: `[A-Z][a-z]{2}` matches only words which have a length of 3

Comment: here i am trying to check if each letter of a word in a string is capital  and [A-Z][a-z]{2} this should accept any number of letters @Lino

Comment: `[A-Z]` is 1 uppercase letter,`[a-z]{2}` followed by 2 lowercase letters which in total is a word of 3 letters

Comment: irrespective of number of letters i want to check if  if each letter of a word in a string is capital, Which i am not able to do with the above query @Lino

Comment: Checking for proper cased strings is nearly impossible within SQL Server.  if you absolutely have to do this, you are better suited doing it elsewhere.  To clarify this, proper case does not mean *Every letter after a space is capitalised*.  If that is what you want, then this is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Use **BINARY**, which does a byte by byte comparison.

```
SELECT * from proptest WHERE BINARY test='This Is Another Test';
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have asked for in your title is different to your question and comments.  Either you don't understand what Proper Case actually is or you just need to check for a capital letter at the start of each word.

If you are actually trying to verify Proper Casing, you will need to also handle all the wonderful variation that the English language bestows upon us.  For example, should `Sean McDonald` count as Proper Case?  What about `Sean Mcdonald`?  Then there is `MacDonald` and `Macdonald` and *then* there is the fun you get to have with hyphenated or abbreviated words.  Should `O'Leary` and `Don't` be treated the same way?

In short this is nearly impossible to get right.  Especially all on your own in SQL.

---

That said, if you just want to find all strings that have a lower case letter first you can do the following:

```
declare @t table(t nvarchar(100));
insert into @t values('This Is Another Test'),('This is another Test');

select *
from @t
where t collate Latin1_General_CS_AS not like '% [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%';    -- For some reason [a-z] still matches upper case letters on my machine.
```

Output:

```
+----------------------+
|          t           |
+----------------------+
| This Is Another Test |
+----------------------+
```